# How can I redirect all sub-directories to root using htaccess or httpd.conf?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache, apache-config

I have an index file that builds content based on *n* PATH_INFO variables.

Example:

```
site.com/A/B/n/
```

should use index.php at either:

```
site.com/index.php?var1=A&var2=B&varN=n
 - or - 
site.com/index.php/A/B/n/
```

instead of:

```
site.com/A/B/n/index.php || which doesn't exist ||
```

So far I've tried a number of variations of:

```
RedirectMatch ^/.+/.*$ /
```

with no success.

I have an inelegant and unscalable solution here:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?p1=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4 [NC,L]
```

**Problems with this solution:**

- Inelegant and unscalable, requires manual line for each subdirectory
- Fails with non alphanumeric characters (primarily +,= and &) ex. site.com/ab&c/de+f/
  (note, even changing the regex to ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-**\+\=\&**]+)/?$ does little to help and actually makes it error out entirely)

Can you help?

Comment: So .. which do you prefer: `site.com/index.php?var1=A&var2=B&varN=n` (requires multiple rules) or `site.com/index.php/A/B/n/` (can be done with single rule) ?

Comment: I'm up for either.  All being equal I'd prefer the one with one line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Option 1:** (`site.com/index.php?var1=A&var2=B&varN=n`):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p1=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4 [QSA,L]
```

1. You had `[NC]` flag ... so there were no need to have `A-Z` in your pattern.

2. Instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9_-\+\=\&]` or `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]` I use `[^/]` which means *any character except slash /*.

3. `[QSA]` flag was added to preserve existing query string.

**Option 2:** (`site.com/index.php/A/B/n/`):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

In reality, if you do not plan to show that URL anywhere (like, 301 redirect etc), the last line can easily be replaced by `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]` -- you will look for original URL using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in your PHP code anyway.

Comment: Above and beyond, LazyOne.  It's a thing of beauty.  It even cures the plus sign mod_rewrite problem I've read so much about.  Great work.

Comment: what should I do if I have a sub-directory in the rott directory with the same name as the url? lets say i wish to access 'www.domain.com/preferences' but I have preferences folder

Comment: @Tal You have to add it to the "exclusion list" (additional condition) as right now it will/should treat it as access to existing folder by `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` part

Comment: @LazyOne And how do I create this condition/exclusion list?

Comment: @Tal You better create separate question describing your situation. Right now I have no access to any of the Apache servers to verify my ideas (and I need it as I have not used Apache for a few months and do not want to give you wrong advices -- have not been answering such htaccess/Apache questions for over a year now -- need some test environment to check my thoughts/ideas **before** answering).

Comment: @LazyOne [New Question Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28069396/angular-spa-integration-with-apache)

Comment: Option 2 is best to build a simple RESTful API. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4):

Adding the following will redirect all traffic (for files that do not exist) to the index page:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [NC]
```

Then, you can make your decision in index.php by parsing the 'REQUEST_URI'

Comment: can you tell me what is the use of first two lines.?

Comment: @PushkerYadav if the request filename is different from -f (file) or -d (directory)

Answer (score 0):

RewriteRule ^/.+ / [R=301,L]

any url with any kind of path beyond root will be redirected to root.

```
^ = start of url
/ = a slash
.+ = 1 or more characters
```