# AngularJS - Why when changing url address $routeProvider doesn't seem to work and I get a 404 error

Tags: apache, angularjs

My `$routeProvider` is configured like this:

```
teachApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,       $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/teach/', {templateUrl: 'views/login_view.html'}).
        when('/teach/overview', {templateUrl: 'views/overview_view.html'}).
        when('/teach/users', {templateUrl: 'views/users_view.html'}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/teach/'});
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Within the app, if I click on a link such as `<a href="/teach/overview">Overview</a>`, the overview partial shows as expected. However, when I manually change the URL in the address bar to exactly the same URL, I get a 404 error. Is `$routeProvider` incorrectly configured?

I'm using MAMP localhost with the root url of the app being `http://localhost/teach/`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to setup your apache to [redirect all paths to root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878245/how-can-i-redirect-all-sub-directories-to-root-using-htaccess-or-httpd-conf).

When you directly open `http://localhost/teach/overview` your web server is trying to serve a page from a route that is not defined.

When, within an angular app, you click on a link with href path of `http://localhost/teach/overview`, Angular steps in, and instead of letting your browser request a page from the server it intercepts your click event and goes to your routeProvider to see which client-side view to display (this is why they call it "single-page apps"). That's why your links work as long as you try not to open them directly.

Beside the apache config you might also want to use `base` tag with href value of `/teach/`:

```
<base href="/teach/" />
```

so that you can have your routeProvider not constrained by fixed prefix:

```
teachApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider,       $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {templateUrl: 'views/login_view.html'}).
        when('/overview', {templateUrl: 'views/overview_view.html'}).
        when('/users', {templateUrl: 'views/users_view.html'}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Answer (score 15):

You can also use # in your URLs.

```
http://localhost/teach/#/overview
```

This will not send a request to the server and will instead be intercepted by the Angular $routeProvider.

Comment: this was a nice, simple solution.