# Spring boot & Spring Security : Forward the invalid urls

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I work with spring boot, thymeleaf, spring security and angularjs
I want all url invalid to return to the home page.
The login page is managed by thymeleaf and the rest by angularjs

So i used a `@Controller` to forward all invalid url to the `localhost:8080/`:

```
@Controller
public class AccueilController {

    // Match everything without a suffix (so not a static resource)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{path:[^\\.]*}")
    public String redirect() {
        // Forward to home page so that route is preserved.
        return "forward:/";
    }
}
```

when connecting if I type `localhost:8080/XXXX`that forward me to the racine after login but if I type `localhost:8080/XXXX/XXXX` that give me a 404 error
after connection I don't have that problem because Angular forward all url correctly.

Answer (score -1):

That's not the default behavior of the web applications. I sugest you to customize the not found page ([Spring Boot and custom 404 error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398385/spring-boot-and-custom-404-error-page)) and then from there create a link to your home;

Comment: I want to direct it to the homepage and do not display the error page