# SpringBoot does not find error templates in production although it finds it in Netbeans

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

During develepment (under Netbeans), if e.g. an internal server error appears in my java SpringBoot(2.1.3) project with jetty, I get the error page named 500.html that is located in the src/main/resources/templates/error/500.html :

[image]

Yet when deployed in production, the 500.html (same for 404.html) does not show because of

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [/error/500], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

although the templates are located in the `/BOOT-INF/classes/templates/error/` folder of the jar :

[image]

These templates are called in an error controller :

```
@Controller
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);

        if (status != null) {
            Integer statusCode = Integer.valueOf(status.toString());

            model.addAttribute("errorCode",
                    statusCode);

            if (statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
                return "/error/404";
            } else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()) {
                return "/error/500";
            }

        }

        return "/error/error";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
```

My project `pom.xml` features the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` as defined below :

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>                
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Please note : all other templates can be found.

I read [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398385/spring-boot-and-custom-404-error-page#comment86129780_37400310) but my project tree seems correct.

What should I do to make SpringBoot find my error templates ?

Any help appreciated,

Answer (score 0):

In the controller above the path to the error pages is wrong. The path should not start with `/`. So instead of

```
 if (statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
                return "/error/404";
            } else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()) {
                return "/error/500";
            }

        }

        return "/error/error";
```

the controller should be (without the leading `/`) :

```
 if (statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
                return "error/404";
            } else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()) {
                return "error/500";
            }

        }

        return "error/error";
```

Please mind that still there should be one leading `/` in the `getErrorPath()` as shown in [Baeldung's post](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page) :

```
@Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
```