# How to handle 404 exceptions using @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, exception, controller-advice

I have a problem with Spring's exception handling for controllers. I have a class annotated with `@RestControllerAdvice` with a couple of `@ExceptionHandler`'s, like this:

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException::class)
fun methodNotSupportedException(
    exception: HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException,
    request: HttpServletRequest
): ResponseEntity<ApiError> {
    logger().error("Method not supported: {}", exception.message)
    val methodNotAllowed = HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
    val apiError = logAndBuildApiError(request, methodNotAllowed, exception)
    return ResponseEntity(apiError, methodNotAllowed)
}
```

and they work perfectly fine. In this case, when I'm trying to use an non-implemented HTTP method like POST:

```
{
    "requestUri": "/api/v1/items",
    "status": 405,
    "statusText": "Method Not Allowed",
    "createdAt": "2023-01-12T16:50:36.55422+02:00",
    "errorMessage": "Request method 'POST' not supported"
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to handle situations when someone is trying to reach an non-existing endpoint, i.e. the correct one is `GET http://localhost:8080/api/v1/items`.

But when I'm trying to reach `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/itemss`, which is of course nonexistent, I recieve a regular Spring whitelabel error page, but I would like to receive a JSON like in the former example:

```
{
    "requestUri": "/api/v1/itemss",
    "status": 404,
    "statusText": "Not Found",
    "createdAt": "2023-01-12T16:52:06.932108+02:00",
    "errorMessage": "Some error message"
}
```

How do I implement a `@ExceptionHandler` so it could handle exceptions related to non-existing resources?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot and custom 404 error page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398385/spring-boot-and-custom-404-error-page)

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page

Comment: Have you tried `@ControllerAdvice` as this doesn't really match an `@RestController` but anything. You would also need an exception handler for a `NoHandlerFoundException`

Comment: @MuratKaragöz I've seen this question, no, this doesn't help me, sadly.

Comment: @M.Deinum changing from RestControllerAdvice to ControllerAdvice doesn't help

Comment: As mentioned you need one for `NoHandlerFoundException` and set `spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found` to `true` else the `DispatcherServlet` will handle it itself.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have set pring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found to true, the logs look fine, but I still receive the whitelabel error page instead of a custom JSON...

Answer (score 1):

`spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found` works in conjunction with
`spring.mvc.static-path-pattern`.  By default, the static path pattern is /**, which includes the whitelabel error pages that you're seeing.

See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/31660
and https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-boot?at=62ba1378568c2c30d30790af
and https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.servlet.spring-mvc.static-content

Option one is to set these two properties in your configuration.

```
spring:
  mvc:
    throw-exception-if-no-handler-found: true
    static-path-pattern: /static
```

Option 2 is to add `@EnableWebMvc` to your spring boot application, and set the `spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found` property to true.  By adding `EnableWebMvc` you'll be getting the `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` bean, which will cause Spring not to initialize the `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` and thereby not set the static-path-pattern.

Comment: Don't add `@EnableWebMvc` (it will also render that property useless) but will disable a lot more then only the static resources.

Comment: See the comment by @M.Deinum.  There are side effects to using `@EnableWebMvc` that you may encounter.  e.g. if you're controllers are annotated with `@Controller` instead of `@RestController`, they will not get handlers registered for their mappings.

Comment: That isn't a side effect, in fact the `@Controller` will work just fine. You won't get pre-configured jackson, the jackson you have will not be integrated into other parts of the framework, no exception handling etc. etc.

Comment: @M.Deinum Are you certain that Controllers will work just fine?  I have a vanilla spring boot api with RestControllers.  If I change them to `@Controller` and add `@EnableWebMvc`, the handlers are not registered.  If I drop `@EnableWebMvc` and leave `@Controller`, they work as expected.  I agree though, `@EnableWebMvc` doesn't play nicely with spring boot.

Comment: Yes, as an `@RestController` itself is also an `@Controller` but just with an added `@ResponseBody` by default for the return types. If you have an `@Controller` with `@EnableWebMvc` you manually need to define the view resolvers etc. without those (and not using `@ResponseBody`) they won't resolve any views.