# Setup custom 403 error page with Spring Boot 3 and Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I recently upgraded to spring boot 3 in an application with Thymeleaf, and my custom 403 pages are no longer working.

Prior to the upgrade, I believe this line was key:
 `http.exceptionHandling().defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint(), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**"));`

Since the upgrade, when I'm not authenticated and try to access a restricted page, I just get this default error screen. This my security filter chain.
[image]

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/",
                                "/login",
                                "/css/**",
                                "/js/**",
                                "/images/**",
                                "/static/favicon.ico",
                                "/favicon.ico",
                                "/fullscreen").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success")
                        .permitAll())
                .exceptionHandling()
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint(), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**"));
        return http.build();
```

When logged in, my 404 and 500 error pages work as expected. I think there is something missing in the way I setup the security filter chain that is preventing this custom 403 error page from working. I couldn't find any resources on how to achieve this with spring boot 3. Any suggestions?

Comment: My custom error page is a styled page to match my application. Why would my application return the browser error page instead of the one from Spring?

Comment: What can I do to return my custom 403 page (located in errors/403.html) instead?

Comment: This is the solution I was using before where Spring + Thymeleaf automatically handled the error pages. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44515671/8509119

Comment: Also, the reason I need to set `new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint()` is so that it does not redirect to the login page when the user tries to access an unauthorized page. I want to return my 403 page instead.

Comment: Ok, then you have to permit your error page. This is the relevant change in Spring Boot 3: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#dispatch-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from @dur, the solution was to add `spring.security.filter.dispatcher-types=request` to my application.properties file.