# Spring Boot/Angular 4 - Routing in app hits the server

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, routes, angular4-router

I have an Angular 4 (ES6) app that I want to serve from a Spring Boot application.  My Angular app has an index.html, and when the address of http://localhost:8080 is hit, Spring Boot knows to map to the index.html file which in Angular is mapped to "/search".

However, I have another route called "adminlogin" which I would access through

http://localhost:8080/adminLogin

But in this instance, it hits my Spring Boot application, which doesn't have a mapping and then it throws an error.

How do I get my address of http://localhost:8080/adminLogin to go to my Angular app?

Comment: The solution can be found in this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837715/spring-boot-with-angularjs-html5mode/44850886#44850886

Answer (score 24):

I had the similar issue with my SpringBoot 2 and Angular6 app. I implemented the `WebMvcConfigurer` interface to override `addResourceHandlers()` method and redirect to `index.html` when there were no mappings found in spring controllers. this can be done in Spring boot 1.5.x extending the (now deprecated) `WebMvcConfigurerAdaptor` class. this is discussed in details in this stackoverflow thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46854105/2958428
I put my built angular app in this location `target/classes/static` using the `outputPath` field in `angular.json` (previously `.angular-cli.json`).
Here's the sample code:

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppWebMvcConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**/*")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
                @Override
                protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
                    Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);
                    return requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable() ? requestedResource : new ClassPathResource("/static/index.html");
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Since the path `adminlogin` was not mapped in any of the spring `controller` spring application dispatch the request to `/error`, Hence you are getting the error page.

You need to route it back to angular so that the `adminlogin` page will be routed by `Angular`.

Following the simple route to do so.

```
@Controller
public class RouteToAngular implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError() {
        return "/";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

Note: Don't forget to implement the 404 page in Angular.

I hope this will be help.

Answer (score 0):

Im my case, I created a simple view controller using ViewControllerRegistry for every Angular route, redirecting to "/".

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        List<String> urlPatterns = List.of(
                "/login",
                "/app-home",
                "/another_route"
        );

        urlPatterns.forEach(pattern -> registry.addViewController(pattern).setViewName("forward:/"));
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the root URL to work without doing this silliness.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class MvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
                    @Override
                    protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
                        Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);
                        
                        return requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable() ? requestedResource
                                : new ClassPathResource("/static/index.html");
                    }
                });

        registry.addResourceHandler("/**/*")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
                    @Override
                    protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
                        Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);
                        
                        return requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable() ? requestedResource
                                : new ClassPathResource("/static/index.html");
                    }
                });
    }
}
```