# How to remove # from URL , SpringBoot & AngularJs application?

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, url-rewriting

**This is my TuckeyRewriteFilter filter class**

```
public class TuckeyRewriteFilter extends org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter {

    @Override
    protected void loadUrlRewriter(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        String confPath = filterConfig.getInitParameter("confPath");
        ServletContext context = filterConfig.getServletContext();
        try {
            final URL confUrl = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(confPath);
            final InputStream config = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(confPath);
            Conf conf = new Conf(context, config, confPath, confUrl.toString(), false);
            checkConf(conf);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

**This is my springboot main class**

```
public class AdminWebApplication {

    public static final String REWRITE_FILTER_NAME = "rewriteFilter";
    public static final String REWRITE_FILTER_CONF_PATH = "urlrewrite.xml";

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AdminWebApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(objectMapper);
        return objectMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean rewriteFilterConfig() {
        FilterRegistrationBean reg = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        reg.setName(REWRITE_FILTER_NAME);
        reg.setFilter(new TuckeyRewriteFilter());
        reg.addInitParameter("confPath", REWRITE_FILTER_CONF_PATH);
        reg.addInitParameter("confReloadCheckInterval", "-1");
        reg.addInitParameter("statusPath", "/redirect");
        reg.addInitParameter("statusEnabledOnHosts", "*");
        reg.addInitParameter("logLevel", "WARN");
        return reg;
    }
}
```

**This is my urlrewrite.xml**
this file is from resources folder
configuration is works fine, loading login page, but still I have to pass /#login, then it redirect to /login URL, but on browser refresh I ma getting 404 error.
index.html, I have added , I don't want extra domain name after my port id.

```
<urlrewrite default-match-type="wildcard">
    <rule>
        <from>/login</from>
        <to>/login.html</to>//As of now only configured for login page.
    </rule>
    <rule>
        <from>/contact</from>
        <to>/index.html</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

Comment: The part after the `#` doesn't make it to the server and is what angular uses internally for routing. You are trying to solve a client-side issue on the server-side that isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1):

In your js router file (config phase) you need to add:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix(''); 
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

and in your `index.html` file, you need to add:

```
<base href="/">
```

#### Update 1

After implementing above on client side, you need to configure url mapping on server side as well. With `#` , the server ignores whatever is followed after it.

```
http://localhost:8080/#i_will_be_ignored/and_so_do_i
```

So, when you configure `angularjs` to remove `#` from URLs, your above request

```
http://localhost:8080/i_will_be_ignored/and_so_do_i
```

will now hit server with `@path('i_will_be_ignored')` . Now, that will give you `404` because you never mapped any API for it. Thats the reason, you are getting `404` on page refresh.

You need to map all the URLs that doesn't match to `index.html` followed by the unmatched url. Once that's done, `angularjs` will take it from there and redirects to appropriate `route` . I hope this will help you.

[Something like this will help you out here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837715/spring-boot-with-angularjs-html5mode)

Comment: It still I have to enter '#' in url prefix, after adding hashPrefix set to blank.

Comment: do you mean ur angular still routes with `#` ?

Comment: no, it doesnt route to '#' but I have to enter '#' in the URL and then it will redirect to the same page by removing '#' symbol.

Comment: and where are you "entering" `#` in the url ? in the `xml` file of spring\ ?

Comment: I have to type in browser URL '#'.
for example if i have to access my login page then
localhost:8080/#/login > on enter hit it will redirect to localhost:8080/login
and if I directly try to access localhost:8080/login, this is breaking app to 404 error

Comment: I redirected as of now login page to index.html, as you suggested. still on refresh it is 404 error

<urlrewrite>
 <rule>
  <from>http://localhost:8888/#login</from>
  <from>http://localhost:8888/#/login</from>
  <to>/index.html</to>
 </rule>
</urlrewrite>

Comment: @Dnyaneshwar : You should remove the hash from the url mapping now, as u have implemented `$locationProvider.hashPrefix` in angularjs

Comment: Thank for your great support. this works for me !. thanks alot.
I have redirected all my URLs through index.html,

Comment: How can I put rule inside urlrewrite.xml for URL having dynamic parameters ?
For e.g. localhost:8080/sample/getstudentbyid/101

Comment: @Dnyaneshwar : I'll have to check, check regex