# Removing # from URL does not work after deployment - HTTP 404

Tags: angular, spring-boot, seo, url-routing

I am trying to get rid ot `#`-red URLs in my Angular app ([Google recommends it](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-no-hashtags-in-urls-26537.html) in the case that your app does not present indexable content on the first load). The web application is in the `static/` directory of my Spring Boot application.

So I disabled the use of `#`:

```js
export const AppRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
  useHash: false,
  enableTracing: false
});
```

On my local machine evereything works fine e.g.

> http://localhost:4200/cars/berlin

lists all cars in Berlin but

> http://www.example.com/cars/berlin

Gives me HTTP 404 after deploying the site.

I'm not sure why this happens. How can I fix this?

However, the root URL http://example.com is **working correctly**. The content of the website is displayed but any page below cannot be reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing. It is simpler as the length of this answer might suggest.

---

### 1) Move apps to separate paths

I moved all my apps (there are two at the moment) to sub-directories. This means that all my apps are required to work under a base-href as in

```
www.example.com/admin-tool/index.html
www.example.com/web/index.html
```

This is the `ng` command I am using to build the `admin-tool` app:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

BASE_HREF=admin-tool

ng build --aot --prod --base-href /$BASE_HREF/ --output-hashing none --output-path dist/$BASE_HREF --deploy-url /$BASE_HREF/
```

---

### 2) Move apps to the Spring project

Move/copy the content in `dist/` (the output of the `ng build`) to (in my case) `src/main/resources/static` if you're not building it there already:

```
src/main/resources/static/admin-tool
src/main/resources/static/web
```

---

### 3) Do the necessary forwarding

As mentioned in other answers one now has to forward requests to the respective `index.html` "files" (let's just call it like that).

Here is why (as I understand it): Before we did all this, Angular just worked on `#`-ed path which caused the JS code to do the updates based on what's after the `#`. And if I'm getting it right - removing the `#` will essentially mean that the browser is now making GET requests for all those URLs. So from the `cars` example, if I have a place/route http://www.example.com/web/cars/berlin then this will now be a GET request which the server has to handle - in this case forward it to the correct endpoint.

Below is the code I am using in my backend to accomplish this:

```java
@Controller
public class ForwardController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/*")
    public String rectRoot(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "forward:/web/index.html";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/**/{[path:[^\\.]*}")
    public String redirect(HttpServletRequest request) {

        if (request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/admin-tool")) {
            return "forward:/admin-tool/index.html";
        } else if (request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/web")) {
            return "forward:/web/index.html";
        }

        return "forward:/web/index.html";
    }
}
```

---

I don't give it a 100% yet, and I really hope this is just a workaround, but so far I am not having any issues with it.

Now here is why I am doing all this:

Apparently it's recommended to move away from `#`-ed paths for several reasons. Since I am using Angular, I'll have to walk a few more miles in order to get search engine optimization (SEO) going but from what I get ([1], [2], [3]) you should avoid it since Google does not index it. They might only use it as an anchor but if you have AJAX content behind your `#` you're going to have a bad time.

See further [4] about `#!` which also seems to be deprecated by now and also take a look at [5] and [6].

---

[1] https://www.oho.com/blog/explained-60-seconds-hash-symbols-urls-and-seo

[2] https://www.seroundtable.com/google-no-hashtags-in-urls-26537.html

[3] https://www.seroundtable.com/google-no-url-fragments-23449.html

[4] https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/18606/64452

[5] https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

[6] https://snipcart.com/blog/angular-seo-universal-server-side-rendering

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure URL rewriting in your web-server. The configurations are different for different web-servers. Using `#` in the url tells Angular the start of the main page url and the SPA logic works using that. Without `#` Angular can't detect the main page start. So you need to configure it in the web-server configurations.

Comment: Does this mean I have to re-write the URLs on my server? E.g. a http://example.com/cars/berlin to http://example.com/#/cars/berlin ? But why is this working on my local machine?

Comment: It can be configured in your local. Not for all specific url. You just set the url of `index.html`

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow you there. What do you mean by "set the url of `index.html`? But from your answer I get that I'll have to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837715/spring-boot-with-angularjs-html5mode

Comment: What server do you use?

Comment: Spring Boot in particular

Comment: Not backend part, but the web-server under which application will be hosted

Comment: That should be Tomcat but I don't really see me messing with that :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset requested route to `index.html`

This might help:

https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what that does. Does http://example.com/cars/berlin become http://example.com/index.html/cars/berlin or what is the effect?

Comment: @StefanFalk When `http://www.example.com/cars/berlin` is requested, server catches that and looks for what it can do with `/cars/berlin`. When using Angular, it shoud simply pass the `/index.html` and let client do rest of work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-
Make the Build of the project & just go to dist folder & create one file name ".htaccess" & paste the below code in it

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

& save it
or For more refrence please refer this link

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5113