# Spring Boot controller to catch all unconfigured routes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to catch all unconfigured routes once all other controllers have been checked and no route matches.

My controller is as below:

```
@Controller
public class ForwardController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/**/{[path:[^\\.]*}")
    public String redirect() {
        return "forward:/";
    }
}
```

But this does not match : http://localhost:8080/abc/def

May I request some guidance on this?

My goal is to not have to handle /error and catch unconfigured routes which otherwise would lead to /error

I fixed this using:

```
@Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/**/{path:[^\\.]+}").setViewName("forward:/");
  }
```

The only issue now is that images are not rendering.

Comment: What is your goal so? Spring Mvc is built around an idea of mapping java controllers to well defined and non ambiguous paths. Maybe you need a servlet filter or even a servlet that will map to all the requests instead of spring  mvc’s dispatcher servlet?

Comment: I am referring to the solution proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837715/spring-boot-with-angularjs-html5mode. I am trying to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about this. Just referring to:
[Spring catch all route for index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39331929/spring-catch-all-route-for-index-html)

could you try adding this:

```
/{spring:\\w+}
```

to make the above:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{spring:\\w+}")
```

Comment: It works well if the uri has a single segment. For ex: http://localhost:8080/home. But if I have multiple segments, http://localhost:8080/home/article, it fails. Could this be adapted to account for multiple segments?

Comment: Cool! Could you replace with:
```(value = "/**/{spring:\\w+}")```